# I want to create a page in my Flutter app that allow users to search other user profiles by using an attributes filter

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter, I'm working on my first application, this is my first question...I want to create a page in my Flutter application that allow users to search for other users profile by using a filter...let me give you an example...it's like the Google Play Store but instead of showing apps I want the application to show user profiles that obviously signed up to my app before and want to offer a service.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question seems to be very broad and more of opinion based. Please be concise on the problem that you are facing,

Comment: Flutter is just a client technology. You should create a backend for the purpose of storing and creating user profiles. The very very basic workflow is like this: You make an http get/post request to your backend like: http://example.com/search?value=valueToSearchFor, your server looks for the value and returns json or xml which you decode in your Flutter app and show to users. As was already mentioned, your question is too broad for a simple answer